# Vue: timer value doesn't update when using setInterval

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following code for updating the number of seconds elapsed and displaying it:

```
<template>
 
 <div>
   {{timerValue}}
   
 </div>
 
  </template>

<script>
 export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
     
  },

  data() {
    return {
      timerValue: ""
    }
  },

  created()  {
     let seconds = 0;
      this.timerValue = seconds;
      setInterval(function()  {
           seconds++;
      })
  }
};
</script>
```

However the page always displays

```
0
```

What am I doing wrong?

https://codesandbox.io/s/still-cache-1mdgr6?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like following snippet:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      timerValue: 0 // set value default is 0 
    }
  },
  created()  {
      setInterval(() => {
           this.timerValue++;
      }, 1000)
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div>
    {{timerValue}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shuold increment `this.timerValue` instead `seconds`

```js
created()  {
     let seconds = 0;
      this.timerValue = seconds;
      setInterval(function()  {
           this.timerValue++;
      }.bind(this))
  }
```

Or with arrow functions

```js
created()  {
     let seconds = 0;
      this.timerValue = seconds;
      setInterval(() => {
           this.timerValue++;
      })
  }
```

Comment: I think arrow function must be used. When I didn't use it, there was no update

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 points for you to pay attention to

- In the setInterval function you only change the `seconds` variable, not `this.timerValue` at all. So page always shows 0.
- The setInterval function doesn't have interval argument yet, so it won't run every second.
- Also the initialization value is not clear, I think you should understand the logic of the program and spent a little time for understand what you written.

```js
<template>
 
 <div>
   {{timerValue}}
 </div>
 
 </template>

<script>
 export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
     
  },

  data() {
    return {
      timerValue: 0,
    }
  },

  mounted()  { // use mounted much better than created in this case
      setInterval(() => {
           this.timerValue++;
      }, 1000)
  }
};
</script>
```

refs: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: It won't work: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-smoke-3dj65g?file=/src/App.vue

 Arrow function must be used in `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

that's why i always tell people to learn language logic or at least javascript before learning something else

you need to update the react value because javascript doesn't have an api that allows memory cell assignment

```js
<script>
 export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
     
  },

  data() {
    return {
      timerValue: 0 // set default value is number
    }
  },

  created()  {
      setInterval(() => {
           this.timerValue++;
      }, 1_000 /* delay 1s */)
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: It's more of a Vue issue (which is a framework,  not a language). And your code won't display anything other than zero

Comment: i don't think it's vue's problem you're not referencing vue's value but just modifying the local variable `seconds`

Comment: even in javascript you can't do anything with this code as long as you are right in javascript you will be right in vue

Answer (score 0):

I found two things wrong about my code:

1. Using `this` inside a `function()`. An arrow function should be used, like this:

```
setInterval(() => {}
```

2. `this.timerValue = seconds` is not enough to make Vue update `timerValue` when `seconds` is updated. Change of seconds doesn't trigger change of `timerValue`.

It can be solved by using computed property:

```
computed:  {
  timerValue: function()  {
    return this.seconds;
  }
},
```

So the whole code would look like this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-cannon-8qvpn9?file=/src/App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ timerValue }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},

  data() {
    return {
      seconds: 0,
    };
  },

  created() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.seconds++;
    }, 1000);
  },

  computed: {
    timerValue: function () {
      return this.seconds;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```